# Dropdown List Won't Display Selected Option After Submit / Refresh

Tags: forms, dropdown, list

I created a user form on my index page which allows the site visitor to re-order my post loop order based on either most recent posts or highest rated posts. The form works perfectly, the problem is: the post loop loads by most recent as a default, but after they select/submit for the highest rated order, the page refreshes and the dropdown list displays the default option value of "Most Recent Posts" when it should be displaying the current option value of "Highest Rated Posts". This is confusing for the reader because it appears as if they are still seeing the most recent posts when they are in fact seeing the highest rated.

How can I force the dropdown list to stay on the selected option instead of defaulting back to first option after refresh?

Here is my code:

```
<?php $sort= $_GET['sort']; if($sort == "date") { $order= "orderby=date"; } if($sort == "highest_rated") { $order= "orderby=meta_value_num"; } ?>

<form class="formindexfilter" action="#ifilter" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="r_orderby" value="desc">
<select name="r_sortby" id="sorting">
 <option value="date" <?php if ($sort == "date") { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> >Most Recent Posts</option>
 <option value="highest_rated" <?php if ($sort == "highest_rated"){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> >Highest Rated Posts</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong? I just want the dropdown list to accurately describe the loop results all the time. Any help would be extremely appreciated. I've been trying to figure this out for weeks now.

Comment: Are you using any plugin on top of that? Or is that the only code?

Comment: @kaiser There is no plugin associated with it. It's just an example I found and customized it for my site and I got it to work without installing a plugin, I just can't get it to show selected. This is the only code.

Comment: Can I see a link? It's hard for me to believe that that code at the beginning (which checks the `$_GET['sort']` value) is actually doing anything. I'm _very_ sure that you can drop it as the `$_GET['sort']` - or actually the `$_POST` value you are sending - is landing in the main query. The same goes for the `action` and the `method` where the first one probably better stays empty.

Comment: @kaiser The sort function works perfectly, the loop reorders flawlessly. Do you think if that placement of `$_GET['sort']` is unnecessary that it could be affecting the form showing what is selected? I don't think i have `$_POST` in my code anywhere. So if I drop it my code would look like `{<?php if($sort == "date") { $order= "orderby=date"; } if($sort == "highest_rated") { $order= "orderby=meta_value_num"; } ?>}`

Comment: The i believe the action="#ifilter" is placing an anchor within the form so the page will refresh at that page anchor.

Comment: No, there won't be a preceding `{` before your PHP opening tags. That's nonsense. The same for the `}` after the closing tag. And another _no_ on if I believe that it would affect the `selected`. I just say it's unnecessary as it does not affect anything. And parsing unfiltered `$_GET` data is unsafe anyway and opens the door for SQL injections.

Comment: @kaiser I tested it with the $_GET['sort'] value removed, and it still works, but doesn't fix the selected state problem. Any ideas on what might be causing it to not stay selected after refresh? If possible could you give me an edited code example? I'm not terribly good in php, but I've gotten by until now.

Comment: downvoted as this is a pure php question, off-topic to the site

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute for the select is "r_sortby". 
Replace

```
$sort= $_GET['sort'];
```

with

```
$sort = isset( $_GET['r_sortby'] ) ? $_GET['r_sortby'] : 'date';
```

Comment: can you tell me where to put that in my code and if I need to remove any duplicate coding? I'm not very good at implementing snippets of code into larger code correctly.

Comment: Updated my answer with the code that needs replacing.

Comment: I replaced that bit of code with your edit, but the same problem still occurs. I also tried changing the 'date' to 'highest_rated' but there is no change, it still defaults back to 'date' after I submit for 'highest_rated'. The sorting works perfectly, but the dropdown list doesn't display correctly what has been sorted.

Comment: What is the url you get after submitting the form? Can you post a link to a page with the form in it?

Comment: [This](http://rantfire.com/?r_orderby=desc&r_sortby=highest_rated#ifilter) loads the highest rated post loop order, but the drop down still shows that it's most recent.

Comment: I have it working in the default theme Twenty Fourteen. Try it with all plugins deactivated. Also try to [validate your markup](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//rantfire.com/)

Comment: I've deactivated all my plugins except the WP-PostRatings plugin which is used to determine the highest rated posts and it still doesn't show that it's selected after refresh. I checked the w3 validation, but most of the errors look correct to me. It keeps saying there is no attribute right before the attribute is listed.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has two helper functions: [`selected()`](http://queryposts.com/function/selected/) and [`checked()`](http://queryposts.com/function/checked/). Both simply compare two values and if they match, they output either `selected` or `checked` HTML attribute/value pairs. The third argument is `echo`.

Just `var_dump( $_GET );` to see what you got. If you ain't got nice formatting via XDebug enabled, you might want use

```
printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', var_export( $_GET, TRUE ) );
```

instead. Check what you really get in return and check against that. Then simply use the functions:

```
<option <?php selected( 'foo', $_GET['foo'] ); ?> value="foo">Foo</option>
```

And that's it.

---

More info on processing HTML form submission values can be found [in this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17139540/376483). Proceed with caution as you might open the doors for SQL injections if you don't validate and sanitize the `$_POST`ed data properly.

Comment: can you tell me where I would implement the first two code segments? Do I just stick the `printf` code into the back end of the `<?php $sort= $_GET['sort']; if($sort == "date") { $order= "orderby=date"; } if($sort == "highest_rated") { $order= "orderby=meta_value_num"; } ?>` I also don't know where i would put the `var_dump` if I tried that also. I would appreciate it if you could re-paste my code with it implemented, I've already crashed my site once trying to implement it into it's own php statement. I can't implement code very well, but I appreciate the help with this problem.

Comment: This is the "WordPress **Development**" site, so it is expected to be solved by yourself with reading on php.net and other online resources to get behind what `var_dump()`, `var_export()` and `printf()` are meant to do if you don't know already. And no, there won't be a copy/paste ready solution. I'm sorry, but if you need such sort of help, then will have to hire a developer to do that for you. From looking at the code in your question, you are better off doing so as there are tons of things to fix to get this up and running.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bad guy because I don't understand? I see people reposting code on these forums all the time, I thought that was the best way to stay on the same page. There's a million different variations of php coding and it's hard to mix them properly. From the simplicity of your answer I just figured I had to correctly place one of them into my existing code and couldn't seem to do that correctly. This is already up and running, it just doesn't stay selected. Thought it would be a simple fix, but I guess it's not. I don't mean to offend. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where did I state that you are a "bad guy". If you want help, you better stop such imputations. And keep in mind that this is _no_ forum and you and anybody else is not allowed to simply "repost" code as every content added to this site [has a license that you have to respect](http://stackexchange.com/legal#3SubscriberContent). Anyway, your problem is that you don't know how HTTP form processing works. You should read about that in detail - I linked an answer from [so] at the end of the question - and if you still can't work around that, then I suggest to hire a developer.